# print does not work outside function

Tags: python

I am passing list and two functions into a function. Within this function I am assigning to that original list a new list. The function is returning one value based on a property of the new list without difficulty. The problem is that when I attempt to print the now modified list from outside the function (for example in the console in Spyder) the original list is printed instead of the new one.

```
def applyF_filterG(L, f, g):
    i = 0
    newL = []
    while i < len(L):
        fint = f(L[i]) 
        if g(fint) == True:
            newL.append(L[i])
        i = i + 1
    L = newL
    if len(L) == 0:
        le = -1
    else:
        le = max(L)
    return le
```

Sorry I didn't post the code originally. After I run the code and then print the original list is returned. I ran the code in pythontutor and the newly modified list L retained its new assignment until the function finished with the return statement.

Comment: Provide some code please

Comment: If you don't return the new list, how do you intend to print it? Reassigning a variable to a new list does not automagically return it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before continuing, please thoroughly read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) - in particular, ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can describe how your car goes "click clunk" all you want, but the mechanic won't be able to fix it until you bring it to the shop.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not modify the list you passed in to your function:

```
L = newL
```

It merely makes the local name `L` refer to the same object that `newL` refers to.  `L` in the calling scope still refers to the original list.

Instead do

```
L[:] = newL
```

This assigns to a slice which mutates the object referred to by the local name `L`.

For an extended discussion of this see [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by [Ned Batchelder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14343/ned-batchelder).

By the way, your entire function can be written more idiomatically as:

```
def applyF_filterG(L, f, g):
    L[:] = [item for item in L if g(f(item)) is True]
    return -1 if not L else max(L)
```

You can leave off the `is True` if `g()` only returns `True` or `False`.

Comment: Thanks that worked and the website will be an interesting read.

Answer (score 2):

If you could post an example of the code, that could be helpful.

Based on what you said, it seems like the new list is just stored as a local variable for the function. If you have the function return the oldlist (after it's been modified by the function), that would probably fix the issue.

Example:(I think this is what you have now, z being the returned list property)

```
def function(oldlist, x, y):
    oldlist = newlist
    return z

z=function(oldlist, x, y)
print oldlist
```

This change might help you:

```
def function(oldlist, x, y):
    oldlist = newlist
    return oldlist, z

oldlist, z=function(oldlist, x, y)
print oldlist
```

Let me know if that works

Comment: The code is for an exam and the grader will not tolerate print statements within the code.

Comment: Also, the largest element (le) is the only thing that should be returned.